# Android : Edit text value

Tags: android

I created a simple login app. It works fine. But i have one problem. When I login and navigate to next page and again come back to login page for another login , the credentials that I entered remains as such. **I want the edit text to be empty when I visit the page next time**. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Clear them just before you "navigate to next page"

Comment: rather than on onresume just clear it when you call new activiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `onResume`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    edtEmail.setText("");
    edtPassword.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    yourEditText.setText("");
    super.onResume();
}
```